# Why does chown 600 id_rsa fix permissions issue?

Tags: ssh, permissions

I recently imported my keys to a new machine (Mac) and forgot to modify the permissions to 600. In doing so, I accidentally wrote `chown` instead of `chmod`. Strangely, this fixed the permission issue as can be seen here:

```
% git pull origin develop
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/Users/m/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/Users/m/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
git@<redacted>: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
%
% sudo chown 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Password:
%
% ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa
-rw-r--r--@ 1 600  staff  1679 Mar 25 15:14 /Users/m/.ssh/id_rsa
%
% git pull origin develop
From <redacted>
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
%
% ssh <redacted>
The authenticity of host '<redacted> (<redacted>)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is <redacted>.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '<redacted>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Warning: your password will expire in 5 days
Last login: Fri Jul 27 19:51:32 2018 from <redacted>
-bash-4.2$
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: try typing `man chown`

Comment: You might get better answers here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I cannot find any official explanation (yet) but I *guess* the rationale is: if you're not the owner of the file and yet you're trying to use it, it's obvious you don't mind the file not having the `600` mode; in fact it can't be `600` in such case. If you "fixed" the permissions somehow, you would lose access to the key in the first place; this is not useful for *you*. Besides you're neither the owner nor root, so you can't possibly "fix" the permissions (unless with `sudo` but no tool should assume this). It seems the tool *you* run tries to mind *your* business, not somebody else's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [OpenSSH](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_7_7/authfile.c#L140) source code, `ssh` only checks permissions on the private key file if the file's owner is the user running `ssh`. If the file belongs to another user then ssh will let anyone who can read the file use it.

```
if ((st.st_uid == getuid()) && (st.st_mode & 077) != 0) {
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--owner ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--permissions
    error("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
    error("@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @");
    error("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
    ...
```

This doesn't appear to be spelled out in the [man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh).

The source code contains this comment indicating the behavior is on purpose:

```
/*
 * if a key owned by the user is accessed, then we check the
 * permissions of the file. if the key owned by a different user,
 * then we don't care.
 */
```

As a practical matter, checking permissions on a key file which belongs to another user wouldn't improve security. If you can read the file, you could work around the permissions check by making a copy of the file and restricting permissions on the copy.

Answer (score -2):

The chmod command stands for "change mode", and allows changing permissions of files and folders, also known as "modes" in UNIX. The chown command stands for "change owner", and allows changing the owner of a given file or folder, which can be a user and a group.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP already knows this. What you wrote doesn't solve the mystery at all.

Comment: An explanation of what chown 600 does would answer the question